# IN clause for multiple columns *and* values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to save time at using the "IN" clause.

In a file that has the same values in several columns, what I would normally do is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE COLUMN_1 IN (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, ...)
AND COLUMN_2 IN (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, ...)
AND COLUMN_3 IN (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, ...);
```

Is there a IN-like clause that can achieve the same with only one equivalence?

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) IN (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, ...);
```

Comment: There is syntax similar to that, but it doesn't do what you want (it looks at triples rather than at each column individually).

Comment: How many values do you have to check for each column? I would recommend adding a table that contains the data you want to compare to and join to that. A huge advantage to such a method is that you won't need to change your query if the data to compare to changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid repeating the values using the following technique:

```
WITH DATAA ( INPUTS ) AS (
    SELECT
        'VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, ...'
    FROM
        DUAL
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE_1 T1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATAA.INPUTS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) ALL_VALUES
        FROM
            DATAA
        CONNECT BY
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATAA.INPUTS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    ) T2 ON T1.COLUMN_1 IN (T2.ALL_VALUES)
            AND T1.COLUMN_2 IN (T2.ALL_VALUES)
            AND T1.COLUMN_3 IN (T2.ALL_VALUES);
```

Cheers!!